# Show all sections toggle in jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I have four of the ".content" sections on a page.I want to be able to toggle each section but also show ALL of the sections to display all of the ".content". When I tried to you add a show all button, the toggle would stop working. Still getting used to jQuery, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the structure of the HTML:

```
<div class="row add-top">
         <div class="span4">

         <p class="expand"><a href="#">Show All</a></p>
          <p class="contract"><a href="#">Hide All</a></p>


    <p class="heading"><strong>Week 01 - Welcome!</strong></p><!--  WEEK --> 
    <section class="content">

        <p></p>
    </section>
    </div>  


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".heading").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
        $(".content").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        $(".expand").click(function () {
            $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
            $(".content").hide();
            //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
            $(".contract").click(function () {
                $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
            });
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: what is the `expand` and `contract` elements

Comment: `expand` and `contract` would show all four of content sections at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $contents = $(".content").hide();
    $(".heading").click(function () {
        var $next = $(this).next(".content").stop(true, true).slideToggle(500);
        $contents.not($next).hide();
    });
    $(".expand").click(function () {
        $contents.stop(true, true).slideDown()
    })
    $(".contract").click(function () {
        $contents.stop(true, true).slideUp()
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wg5fB/)

Comment: I think `var $contents = $(".content").hide();` should be `var $contents = $(".content");`

Comment: @RohanKumar the OP is initially hiding the content elements... so it should be ok

Comment: I was not talking about `hiding the elements`, I just wanted to know, that the assignment of `selector` is possible after  using `hide()`.

Comment: @RohanKumar yes.. because the plugin methods are chained

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine all `click events` as these all `working same` and use [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown) in place of [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle), also don't use `next()` use `$('.content') selector` to `toggle` like,

```
$(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".heading, .expand, .contract").click(function () {
        $(".content").hide().slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r9JTS/)

And if you have `multiple-content` then use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) try this,

```
$(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".heading, .expand, .contract").click(function () {
        $(".content").hide();

        // let row is parent for every div containnig heading, expan, contract
        $(this).closest('.row').find(".content").slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

[jQuery toggle() to hide/show collapse content](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-toggle-example-to-display-and-hide-content/)

[Toggle-Jquery](http://jqueryui.com/toggle/)

May be it will helpful for you.Thanks.